# Ajax Request Error affects all other users

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application that utilizes jQuery, c#, MVC 4.
There are functions that calls ajax requests which connects to controller.

The problem here, I'm getting intermittent errors.  It used to happen when someone triggers an error and it will hang-up the other users.

sample error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But it will work again once the ajax requests has been cleared in IIS.
We think its because of multiple ajax requests happening with the web application.

Is there a way in jquery or in c# itself to prevent other users to get hanged-up when someone triggers an error?

Thank you.

Comment: a little bit to less information. log where it goes wrong (first requets) and see what happens. go from there.

Comment: async can help , sometimes

Comment: but is there a way to prevent affecting other users when someone started experiencing issues?

Comment: @ARUN yes it does, but not quite appropriate at all times especially for bigger forms that needs to populate a lot of fields.

Comment: @SyntaxError where is the error occuring , there is some async jquery methods, I am not familiar with it. please have a look at it, or you can use try catch in the javascript to handle error...